# Xamarin Forms reverse geolocation on iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net, xamarin.forms, geolocation, cross-platform

I have created a cross-platform app using the Geolocator plugin.

On Android, the GetAddressesForPositionAsync returns a barrel full of addresses for me to choose the best match. iOS, however, brings back only 1.

I've read that this is due to the native method of getting location, the CLLocationManager for this which only ever returns a single best match.

Has anyone ever come across this and increased that number within the confines of that NuGet package?

If not, which package will do a better job?

Failing that, was something native created to bridge the gap?

Comment: Have you tried switching to Xamarin essentials for Geocoding? I don't think they limit it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geocoding?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=ios

Comment: Just have, thanks for the tip.

Unfortunately it's still only returning a single Placemarker, which is the same details as the CLLocationManager object.